# jQuery Partial array match user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've been working on a postcode checker which I need to have a partial match on the array. ie: if the user current uses L20 it shows true but if the uses L20 1WE if shows false.

I need it to read the array and if any part of the user input matches it shows true.

I have a demo up here: https://codepen.io/paulmaloney/pen/dfa0603f200a8f5be89b0a10d7ba80f6

```
var postcodes = ["PR8","PR9","WA11","L1","L2","L20","L80"];

$('#searchForm').submit(function(){
    var postcode = $('#searchForm input').val();  
    if($.inArray(postcode.toUpperCase(), postcodes ) > -1){
        $('#result').html('Yes, we cover your area!');
    }else{
        $('#result').html('Sorry, it looks like we do not cover that area yet.');
    }

    return false;
});
```

That's my code thus far. I know I'm missing something silly but can't work it out

Comment: `L20 1WE` ? I can't understand this part: `if the user current uses L20 it shows true but if the uses L20 1WE if shows false`

Comment: L20 1WE if shows false must be true as he wants partial matches

Comment: It doesn't partial match, it's only working for an exact match currently.

Comment: What do you mean by *part* ? Is it a sequence of characters between spaces or the string's start and end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the input then use `some()` and `includes()` like the following way:

```js
var postcodes = ["PR8","PR9","WA11","L1","L2","L20","L80"];

$('#searchForm').submit(function(){
    var postcode = $('#searchForm input').val().toUpperCase();
    postcode = postcode.trim().includes(' ') ? postcode.split(' ') : postcode.match(/.{1,3}/g);
    if(postcode.some(i => postcodes.includes(i))){
        $('#result').html('Yes, we cover your area!');
    }else{
        $('#result').html('Sorry, it looks like we do not cover that area yet.');
    }

    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="search" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="s" class="form-control covered-area-search-input" placeholder="Enter the first half of your postcode...">
  <input type="submit" value="Search"/> 
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Maybe, splitting and matching do not required. Simply checking if the current value includes any item of the array.

```js
var postcodes = ["PR8","PR9","WA11","L1","L2","L20","L80"];

$('#searchForm').submit(function(){
    var postcode = $('#searchForm input').val().toUpperCase();
    if(postcodes.some(i => postcode.includes(i))){
        $('#result').html('Yes, we cover your area!');
    }else{
        $('#result').html('Sorry, it looks like we do not cover that area yet.');
    }

    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="search" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="s" class="form-control covered-area-search-input" placeholder="Enter the first half of your postcode...">
  <input type="submit" value="Search"/> 
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome that's almost it! It still shows false if the user doesn't add a space ie: L201WE.

Comment: @Paul, if there is no space then you can chuck the input with 3 characters, updated the answer, please check:)

Comment: This will still fail is the input is something like `L1ABC`. It should match because `L1` (two characters not three) is in the array.

Comment: You can use something like `postcodes.some(c => userInput.contains(c))` (and maybe lowercase both `c` and `userInput`).

Comment: @Titus, `contains()` is a DOM method (*indicates whether a node is a descendant of a specified node*). Though it seems your catch is valid and I have added another solution, thanks:)

Comment: I've meant to say `.includes(..)` (as in [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)) or maybe `.startsWith(..)` will be better, that depends on what the OP wants, it is not clear what he means by *part*.

Answer (score 1):

[$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) does a strict check between `postcode` and values in `postcodes` array.

Since you're checking that `postcode` entered by user is prefixed by any `postcode` in `postcodes` array you need to write a custom filter for that.

Find every matched postcode in `postcode` array to the first part of the post code entry.

```
postcodePart = postcode.toUppercase().split(' ').shift()
matches = postcodes.filter(
  postcode => new RegExp("^" + postcode + "$").test(postcodePart)
)
```

Check the length of the matched postcode and verify that there is a match.

```
if (matches.length == 1) {
   $('#result').html('Yes, we cover your area!');
} else {
   $('#result').html('Sorry, it looks like we do not cover that area yet.');
}
```